# Accessing docker container in AWS from localhost

Tags: python, docker, amazon-ec2, pycharm

I have a python docker container up and running on EC2-instance.
How can I use this python as interpreter in my local IDE (PyCharm)?

Comment: did you manage to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to File -> Settings

Then Project -> Project Interpreter

[image]

Then on top right on the gear icon, click 'Add'.

[image]

Then go to SSH interpreter, fill in the Host IP of your EC2-instance and the username.

[image]

Next, fill the password or add your private key (this assumes you have the right for SSH into the instance)

[image]

Finally, choose the python interpreter in the remote instance.

[image]